# Kubernetes Service Port-Forwarded Locally is giving Connection Refused

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, localhost

I've port-forwarded an external API to localhost:3000 using kubectl, and am able to make requests and receive responses through Postman, browser, etc. However, when I build and deploy a Spring application to use the port-forwarded API address and port (i.e. localhost:3000) configuration to receive and process responses, checking the logs of the local Kubernetes pod in which it is deploys shows that the connection is being refused:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
```

I'm failing to understand why the locally deployed pod can't access the URL provided, when it seemingly otherwise works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are deploying this Spring app to a Kubernetes cluster. When the Spring app deploys, it will run inside a container, and localhost:3000 is the port 3000 of the pod the app is running in, it is not the port 3000 of the host. If you cannot access this external service using something like an ingress, maybe you can try running a port forward in a separate container deployed in the same pod as your Spring app.

Comment: I think I understand your reply - so there is no way of allowing access to localhost:3000 from within the pod that the app is running in, other than deploying another pod that port forwards the external service to localhost:3000 in that cluster?

Comment: A container cannot access the ports of the host, unless you configure the docker networking to use host networking. I don't know if this is even possible under k8s running on your local host

Comment: That makes sense :) But it's possible to configure it to use the external service using an ingress, is that correct?

Comment: If you have an ingress in front of the external service, or expose it via a nodeport, then you can access it.